# Redirect to another websites with one path

Tags: html, url, redirect

I would like to redirect some pages but I don't know how to do that.

I want to redirect to different external websites with one path.

It should be the following way:

**mydomain.com/category - Redirects to an website.**

**mydomain.com/category/example - Redirects to another website.**

Does anyone know how to do that and could explain me?

I'm looking forward to your answers!

Best Regards

***Edit:**

I found out by myself now.

I don't need any more help :)*

Comment: Well done for finding out your own solution and making it work by yourself. Please do add the solution you found either to your question above or as an answer below, to help future visitors to this page who may be trying to solve the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to edit html of those pages you can add this following code to redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
   content="0; url=http://www.example.com/">
```